# Почему арифметические операции в bash можно использовать только с целыми числами?

Tags: bash

Например,

```
$((2+2))
```

Работает, а выражение

```
$((0.2+2))
```

нет

Comment: Нет, не работает:
echo $((0,2 + 2))
4

Comment: Потому что баш умеет только целочисленную арифметику. Это шелл, а не калькулятор.

Comment: `bash` работает только с целыми числам. Почему? Это вопрос к разработчикам. Если вы хотите работать с плавающей запятой, то должны делегировать их такому инструменту, как, например, `bc`

Comment: `man bash` *Evaluation is done in fixed-width **integers** with no check for overflow*

Comment: Вот [тут](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks) расписано как и что считается в разных шеллах и языках.